Intuition behind the weighting matrix of a GMM estimator
I'm trying to fully understand the GMM estimator. I hope you can clarify my doubts.
Suppose that $y_i$ is described by the following DGP:
\begin{equation}
y_i = x'_{i} \beta + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}
and $x_i$ is a column vector of predictors of size $K$. Now, suppose that some predictors are endogenous, that is, $E(x_{ji} \epsilon_i) \ne 0$ for some $j=1,2,\ldots,K$.
Let's say I have a vector of instruments $z_i$ of size $L$, with $L > K$, and $E(z_i \epsilon_i)=0$. Furthermore, it is assumed that the instruments in $z$ are valid because $E(z_i \epsilon_i)=0$ and $E(z_i x'_i ) \ne 0$, but not perfectly correlated.
Now, if I understand the GMM estimator correctly, the idea is to exploit the following moment condition: $E(z_i \epsilon_i)=0$ to get a consistent estimator for $\hat{\beta}$. The sample equivalent of my moment condition, in matrix notation, is $\frac{1}{N} Z' \hat{e} =0$, where $\hat{e} = ( y - X \hat{\beta})$ is an $N \times 1$ vector of estimated residuals coming from the initial equation. However, $\frac{1}{N} Z' \hat{e} =0$ creates a system with more equations than variables since $L > K$, and the specification is overidentified. The GMM estimator wants to make the magnitude of $\frac{1}{N} Z' \hat{e}$ as small as possible by minimizing
\begin{equation}
||  \frac{1}{N} Z' \hat{e}||_{A} = (N^{-1}) \hat{e}' Z A Z' \hat{e}
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the chosen weighting matrix. The GMM estimator is the vector of minimizers that minimize $||  \frac{1}{N} Z' \hat{e}||_{A}$. I take first-order derivatives with respect to $\hat{\beta}$ and I get,
\begin{equation}
\hat{\beta}_{GMM} = (X' Z A Z'X)^{-1} X' Z A Z' Y
\end{equation}
However, the lecturer in class claimed that if you choose $A$ to be an identity matrix, this is in general not efficient, and he gave an example saying to consider what happens if there are two instruments of zero means, one drawn from a variable with a variance of 1, and the other from a variable with a variance of 1,000. Moments based on the second instrument will dominate the minimization problem under equal weighting, wasting the information in the first.
Now, please tell me if I interpret the example correctly:
The objective is to minimize the objective function $(N^{-1}) \hat{e}' Z A Z' \hat{e}$, and with $A=I$, I can re-write it as
\begin{equation}
Q(\beta) = \left( N^{-1} \sum_{i} z_i \hat{\varepsilon}_i \right)^{T}  \left( N^{-1} \sum_{i} z_i \hat{\varepsilon}_i \right)
\end{equation}
I can also rewrite $Q(\beta) = Q_1 (\beta) + Q_2 (\beta)$, with $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ referring to the first($z_1$) and second instrument ($z_2$), respectively:
\begin{equation}
Q_1(\beta) = \left( N^{-1} \sum_{i} z^{2}_{1i} \hat{\varepsilon}^{2}_i \right) \propto \sigma^{2}_1 \, E(\hat{\varepsilon}^2) = E(\hat{\varepsilon}^2)
\end{equation}
where $\sigma^{2}_{1}$ is the variance of $z_{1}$. Basically, $Q_1(\beta)$ is the sample equivalent of the variance of the moment condition $E(z_{1i} \varepsilon_i)$.
Similarly,
\begin{equation}
Q_2(\beta) = \left( N^{-1} \sum_{i} z^{2}_{2i} \hat{\varepsilon}^{2}_i \right) \propto \sigma^{2}_2 \, E(\hat{\varepsilon}^2) = 1000 E(\hat{\varepsilon}^2)
\end{equation}
The resulting objective function to minimize will be
\begin{equation}
Q_1(\beta) + Q_2(\beta) = 1001 E(\hat{\varepsilon}^2)
\end{equation}
Thus, moments based on a second instrument will dominate the minimization problem under equal weighting.
Is the interpretation of the example correct?

Contemplate your last equation,
\begin{equation}
Q_1(\beta) + Q_2(\beta) = 1001 E(\hat{\varepsilon}^2)
\end{equation}
In this objective function the variances of the two instruments have been simply added together, and have become a scaling factor of the variance of the residuals. But then, these variances do not matter at all, since the estimator will take the derivative of this and set it equal to zero.
So no, this is not the way to show, even intuitively, why in GMM estimation there exists a weight matrix $\rm A$ that is not the identity matrix, and leads to lower variance (hence increases "efficiency") of the estimator.
The issue here is not the minimization problem itself, but the variance of the estimator. The statement

Moments based on the second instrument will dominate the minimization problem under equal weighting, wasting the information in the first.

is vague and opaque and draws attention away from the variance of the estimator.
It can be proven, that this variance with the optimal weight matrix is always smaller than with the use of any other matrix, the identity matrix included. This is long to show, but I have included a proof here,
https://alecospapadopoulos.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/econometrics-little-things-1.0-2023-03.pdf
topic 3.25,
where I also argue that the value-added of GMM compared to vintage method-of-moments is exactly this increase in efficiency, since everything else can be achieved with MoM alone.
